# Problem installing in pyrad module for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, radius

I have created a virtualenv and tried below command for installing pyrad module:

```
env) C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Python\radius-demo>python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please help me out. My os is windows 10.

Comment: obviously there is no setup.py file in that directory

Comment: to install pyrad use `pip install pyrad`

Answer (score 0):

inside your virtualenv you should run: pip install pyrad

If you are new to virtual enviroments I would recommend reading this article 
https://towardsdatascience.com/virtual-environments-104c62d48c54

Comment: `python setup.py install` is pretty common actually

Comment: I have also tried outside the virtual env. I have used above command because it is mentioned in pyrad documentation. You can check it at [https://pyrad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](https://pyrad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @AmitaYadav if you want to install is using setup.py you obviously have to download pyrad beforehand. why dont you simply use pip?

Comment: @luigigi ok i am fairly new with python myself. Thats why i prefixed with as far as i know. Edited answer.

Comment: @Ahmet no problem. usually its included in every package so you can install the package locally from sources